# Activity removed from Back Stack

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

**Intro**

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Android. However my activity is removed from Back Stack and its `onCreate` method is never called after application is brought in front.

**Scenario**

There are 3 activities in the Back Stack:

- Activity01
- Activity02
- Activity03

When I lock the display (turn it off) I am able to run Camera from the locked screen. The Camera application fails to start when I run it from locked screen (because of missing permission in our MDM application, the behaviour that Camera fails is OK). After Camera fails a 'Camera stopped' dialog is shown. This is also OK. The problem is that after I confirm 'Camera stopped' dialog the Activity03 is removed from the Back Stack. The BackStack looks like this:

- Activity01
- Activity02

Note: The scenario with running Camera app from locked screen is just a shortcut to reproduce the problem. Sometimes the activity is destroyed right after unlocking the display. Unfortunately this is very hard to reproduce and happens only once/twice per day. So I'm using the camera scenario as a shortcut.

If I lock the screen again and run the Camera app from locked screen, the app fails again and now Activity02 is removed. The Back Stack then contains only Activity01:

- Acitivty01

**Solution hints / Discussion**

- I understand that it's perfectly valid to destroy activity anytime by Android OS. However it's `onCreate` method should be called once the application is brought to the front. Or am I missing something?
- Is it valid that Android modifies Back Stack history? Eg. if there is not enough memory left and Android decides to kill your app? I understand if an app is destroyed, but once again: I think it's Back Stack history should be untouched and `onCreate` should be called if app is brought to front.
- I also know that there is `android:persistent` attribute one can add to AndroidManifest's `application` element. However this attribute is ignored if application is not running in "system space". And this is not my case, my device is not rooted and my app has to run in "user space".
- Is there a way to detect that my activity has been removed from Back Stack by system, I mean without user's intention? If yes, then I could recreate the activity after app resumes. Unfortunately I'm not able to distinguish between these 2 scenarios - 1. activity was destroyed intentionally by user, 2. activity was destroyed by Android OS (eg. due to lack of memory)

**Edit**

Log output:

```
Screen locked:

03-05 23:03:41.430 27370-27370/com.myapp I/*atformAbstractActivity: com.myapp.ui.Activity03.onPause()
03-05 23:03:41.440 27370-27370/com.myapp I/*atformAbstractActivity: com.myapp.ui.Activity03.onStop()

Screen unlocked:

03-05 23:03:54.514 27370-27370/com.myapp I/*atformAbstractActivity: com.myapp.ui.Activity03.onRestart()
03-05 23:03:54.514 27370-27370/com.myapp I/*atformAbstractActivity: com.myapp.ui.Activity03.onStart()
03-05 23:03:54.514 27370-27370/com.myapp I/*atformAbstractActivity: com.myapp.ui.Activity03.onResume()
03-05 23:03:54.554 27370-27370/com.myapp I/ActivityManagerProxy: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@425a4370 time:821210127
03-05 23:03:54.844 27370-27370/com.myapp I/*atformAbstractActivity: com.myapp.ui.Activity03.onPause()
03-05 23:03:56.205 27370-27370/com.myapp I/*atformAbstractActivity: com.myapp.ui.Activity03.onStop()
03-05 23:04:00.350 27370-27370/com.myapp I/*atformAbstractActivity: com.myapp.ui.Activity03.onDestroy()
```

**Edit 2**

Output of ActivityManager.MemoryInfo added:

Memory status when `Activity03.onStart()` called for the first time:

```
availMem = 315891712
foregroundAppThreshold = 50331648
hiddenAppThreshold = 100663296
visibleAppThreshold = 62914560
secondaryServerThreshold = 100663296
threshold = 100663296
totalMem = 872062976
lowMemory = false
```

Memory status when `Activity03.onStart()` called after screen unlocked:

```
availMem = 316497920
foregroundAppThreshold = 50331648
hiddenAppThreshold = 100663296
visibleAppThreshold = 62914560
secondaryServerThreshold = 100663296
threshold = 100663296
totalMem = 872062976
lowMemory = false
```

Memory status when `Activity03.onDestroy()` called after screen unlocked:

```
availMem = 317919232
foregroundAppThreshold = 50331648
hiddenAppThreshold = 100663296
visibleAppThreshold = 62914560
secondaryServerThreshold = 100663296
threshold = 100663296
totalMem = 872062976
lowMemory = false
```

**Edit 3**

Stacktrace of `onDestroy()` method call:

```
"<1> main@830034095704" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at sk.plaut.mobileplatform.client.ui.MainActivity.onDestroy(MainActivity.java:57)
      at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5428)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1117)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3473)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3504)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:138)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1252)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java:-1)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java:-1)
```

Comment: Can you explain what your Activity3 is doing? Is it working with camera as well? Have you made sure that your Activity3 is not cleared because of a crash?

Comment: Yes I'm sure Activity03/02/... did not crash. I ensured it in logs and by debugger as well. Camera is just another application which runs in different process. It's launched by Android after user click the icon in locked screen. And as I mentioned - running Camera is just a shortcut to reproduce the problem. Sometimes Activity03/02/.. is destroyed and removed from Back Stack just at time of unlocking the screen (no need to run Camera application). However this is very rare scenario.

Comment: When your activity i removed from the back stack do you get the `onDestroy()` or `onSaveInstanceState()` callback?

Comment: I just get `onDestroy()`. `onSaveInstanceState(...)` is not called.

Comment: Do you have any logs from this happens?

Comment: Please see the logs in original question. What's interesting is the `ActivityManagerProxy: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy` entry in the logs. However this record is there event if `Activity03` is not destroyed, just stopped.

Comment: It looks like that your activity is getting killed because of a finish call because your activity goes to `onResume`. The likelihood of your activity for being killed when in the `onResume` state is very minimal. Have you checked the RAM of the phone when this happens?

Comment: Please see memory status in original question. It seems OK to me.